# No puedo hacer mi header responsivo

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Vista Celular:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Soy incapaz de poner el botón de "cerrar sesion" debajo de la imagen cuando a la web se accede por el celular.

```css
.LOGO {
    height: auto;
    line-height: 0;
    margin: -3px 20px -5px 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 240px;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<header class="bg-dark border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
        <div b-weq4c8fyil="" class="navbar-header p-2" style="
">
            <div b-weq4c8fyil="" class="p-2 ms-5 mb-4 LOGO start-0">
                <a href="/Acceso/Login">
                    <img b-weq4c8fyil="" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__480.jpg
    " alt="Logo">
                </a>
            </div>
            <a class="btn btn-danger position-absolute end-0 mt-5 me-5" href="/Acceso/Salir">Cerrar Sesión</a>
        </div>
    </header>
```

Estoy utilizando Bootstrap 5; he intentado usar `display: flex` o `display: grid` pero no puedo arreglarlo.

Comment: Mmmmm, en el snippet parece funcionar como esperás que funcione. Pregunta clásica: _¿limpiaste la caché del navegador?_

Comment: creo que falta agregar bootstrap al snippet pero nosé cómo se hace

Comment: En la edición que hice, ya lo agregué :) A la izquierda, hay un botón que dice _Agregar librería externa_. Se agrega desde allí.

Comment: Estoy probando tu código en mi editor de código y están todo bien:/ o cuál es el problema en sí?

Comment: Lo probaste como simulando un celular? En pantalla monitor funciona correctamente, pero en el modo celular el boton se ubica por encima de la imagen

Comment: De mi parte, debo decir que lo probé en Firefox (v106.0.5), y anteriormente también lo probé _como simulando un celular_ como decís, y sigue mostrando como esperás que se muestre.

Comment: Qué raro... no sé qué hacer entonces... Se cierra la pregunta?

Comment: ¿Será que el código de tu `form` está influyendo en la posición de tu botón? Hasta ahora no podemos reproducir tu problema. Lo probé en Brave y también funciona correctamente.